# how to get assemblyinfo into XAML in windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, assemblyinfo

is there any way we can bind or use the app version and other assembly info in Xaml in windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Package Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.aspx)

So get the package info in your C# code:

```
var myPackage = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
```

and then display into application using TextBlock or other Control.

Comment: can't we bind these info directly to xaml. i.e. with no code behind.